Troubles while packing Python Flet script
I work on an M1 Mac, and I'm tryin to pack a simple Python(3.11.4) script(PyCharm 17.0.11) named main.py:
import flet
print('packed')

I used the Flet's(0.23.2) guide:
Guide doesn't tell, but i created REQUIREMENTS.TXT:
flet==0.23.2

arch -arm64 python3 -m pip install flet
(tried to install it from PyCharm settings, too)
arch -arm64 python3 -m pip install PyInstaller
flet pack main.py
What I get after last command is

BUILD directory
main.spec
DIST directory empty

PyInstaller.utils.osx.IncompatibleBinaryArchError:/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/watchfiles/_rust_notify.cpython-311-darwin.so is incompatible with target arch arm64 (has arch: x86_64)!
P.S. if i just remove:
import flet,
so my script becomes just:
print('packed'),
in DIST directory I find my executable and it works (it prints 'packed'),
that's why I'm almost sure that troubles are (I don't know how) in the Flet's installation.
Please help, thanks
